# T-SQL : compare values return occurrences matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to "score" two columns of addresses based on how many characters appear in common.Below is how the data appears and the intended result. Any solutions will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm: space doesn't count as a character, 123 Foo St / 321 Foooo St is only 8, not 10, and likewise 123 Foooo St / 321 Foo St is only 8, not 10?

Comment: That is correct space does not count as a character.

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-the-longest-common-substring/ ? Note: this is a relatively expensive thing to compute

Comment: Out of interest, what's your business goal for this query?

Comment: Comparing participants with an existing address with an address provided by another business and determining if the returned address is unique or the same address. Our preference would be to pay only for unique addresses. The character "score" along with some other rankings   will hopefully get us close.

Answer (score 0):

With the help a a Table-Valued-Function and a Cross Apply

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Address1 varchar(25),Address2 varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
('123 Foo St','12 Foo'),
('123 Foo St','Bar Street'),
('123 Foo St','321 Foo St'),
('123 Foo St','Bar Lane')


Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Cnt = count(*)
                From (Select Distinct RetSeq,RetVal From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Char](replace(A.Address1,' ',''))) C1
                Join (Select Distinct RetVal From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Char](replace(A.Address2,' ',''))) C2
                  on C1.RetVal=C2.RetVal
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Address1    Address2    Cnt
123 Foo St  12 Foo      5
123 Foo St  Bar Street  2
123 Foo St  321 Foo St  8
123 Foo St  Bar Lane    0
```

The UDF if Interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Char] (@String varchar(max))
Returns Table
As
Return (
    with   cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N) As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d,cte1 e,cte1 f)

    Select RetSeq=N
          ,RetVal=Substring(@String,N,1) 
     From  cte2
) 
--Max 1 Million Observations
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Char]('this is a string')
```

Comment: Thank you I can work with this.I up voted but as a new participant it did not register publicly. Thanks again.

Comment: @M.Butter Happy it helped.  Cheers :)